# FOR LOOP fails in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I try to develop some code that loops through a set of geometries (ordered by id)  and deletes from the next neighboring geometry based on the size, but  my syntax seems at the loop seems to be incorrect.

When I run:

```
WITH firstblocks AS(

SELECT  ST_Buffer(ST_Line_Substring(the_geom, 8*n/length,
  CASE
    WHEN 8*(n+1) < length THEN 8*(n+1)/length
    ELSE 1
  END),4, 'endcap=flat join=mitre mitre_limit=3.0' ) As the_geom

FROM
  (SELECT 
  ST_LineMerge(geom) AS the_geom,
  ST_Length(geom) As length
  FROM example_route_single_feature
  ) AS t

CROSS JOIN generate_series(0,CEIL(length/8)::int) AS n
WHERE n*8/length < 1

)

SELECT the_geom FROM firstblocks;

DO
$do$
BEGIN
    FOR i IN the_geom LOOP
        IF ST_Area(i) <= ST_Area(lead(i)) 
        THEN
            ST_Difference(i, lead(i)) ;
        ELSE 
            ST_Difference(lead(i), i) ;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END     
$do$
```

I get the error:

```
SQL error: WITH firstblocks AS(  SELECT  ST_Buffer(ST_Line_Substring(the_geom, 8*n/length,   CASE   WHEN 8*(n+1) < length THEN 8*(n+1)/length   ELSE 1   END),4, 'endcap=flat join=mitre mitre_limit=3.0' ) As the_geom    FROM   (SELECT    ST_LineMerge(geom) AS the_geom,   ST_Length(geom) As length   FROM example_route_single_feature   ) AS t    CROSS JOIN generate_series(0,CEIL(length/8)::int) AS n WHERE n*8/length < 1  )  SELECT the_geom FROM firstblocks;  DO $do$ BEGIN   FOR i IN the_geom LOOP      IF ST_Area(i) <= ST_Area(lead(i))       THEN            ST_Difference(i, lead(i)) ;         ELSE            ST_Difference(lead(i), i) ;         END IF;     END LOOP; END        $do$ returned 0 [ERROR:  syntax error at or near "the_geom"
LINE 26:   FOR i IN the_geom LOOP
                    ^
]
```

I'm a PostGIS beginner and not so fit with the PostgrSQL-Syntax, so I would be very happy if someone can point whats wrong with the code.

I'm using PostGIS 2.5.1

Comment: Is this inside a function or is that the full command you are executing? What error message do you get?

Comment: I updated the question, please take a look...

Comment: SQL is not a procedural language and you cannot declare a global variable (for example the_geom). You can either create a new function and apply this function to the_geom OR, in your case, you can simply use `CASE`: `SELECT CASE WHEN... THEN... ELSE... FROM firstblocks`

Comment: This is a pretty heavy question; you are mixing multiple and fundamentally different grammars and abstraction levels of SQL here, and while at it, missed some core concepts of both (which also diminishes the effect of learning I guess...). IMO, lightly going the PL/pgSQL route for more or less standard DB operations is bad practice; SQL is powerful, and optimized to do these tasks. I think it may be worth to redefine this question; outline the task and expected results in detail, and ask about the pure SQL part first; if your task hits a limit of plain SQL, an answer should cover it.

Comment: Not trying to patronize here, don't get me wrong...but answering *why* it doesn't work like that alone would fill pages of a book ;-)

Comment: I created a new question wich is hopefully more clear and also more helpful for everyone: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363025/how-to-run-a-moving-window-function-in-a-conditional-statement-in-postgis-for-bu