# How to run a moving window function in a conditional statement in PostGIS for buffer artifact removing?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I try to remove the artifacts which occur when running the `ST_Buffer` function in PostGIS PostGIS 2.5.1 (See picture). For this case I wrote a function that should loop trough every segment (row) and erase (`ST_Difference`) the Polygons with the smaller areas (I assume the "normal-shaped") from the bigger ones (With additional artifacts).
[image]

```
--CREATE TABLE line(name char(10), geom geometry);
--INSERT INTO line VALUES('line','LINESTRING(0 0,30 10,40 30,70 40)');

WITH firstblocks AS(

SELECT  row_number() Over() AS id, ST_Buffer(ST_Line_Substring(the_geom, 8*n/length,
  CASE
    WHEN 8*(n+1) < length THEN 8*(n+1)/length
    ELSE 1
  END),4, 'endcap=flat join=mitre mitre_limit=3.0' ) As the_geom

FROM
  (SELECT 
  ST_LineMerge(geom) AS the_geom,
  ST_Length(geom) As length
  FROM line
  ) AS t

CROSS JOIN generate_series(0,CEIL(length/8)::int) AS n
WHERE n*8/length < 1

)

--Erase the smaller geometry from the bigger one
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ST_Area(the_geom) <= ST_Area(lead(the_geom) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id))
        THEN ST_Difference(the_geom, lead(the_geom) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id))
        ELSE ST_Difference(lead(the_geom) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id), the_geom)
    END AS new_geom
FROM firstblocks;
```

The code works but loading the data as a new layer in the QGIS-Database Manager throws out the error: `There was an error creating the SQL layer ...`
Somehow I am struggling with the conditional statements, while using a moving window approach. How can I combine them successfully?

Comment: What buffer artifacts?  Is there a PostGIS or GEOS ticket for this?

Comment: Ok, I see the artifact now.  Here's a reproducer: `SELECT ST_Buffer( 
  ST_LineSubstring('LINESTRING(0 0,30 10,40 30,70 40)'::geometry, 0.25, 0.375), 
  4, 'endcap=flat join=mitre mitre_limit=3.0');`

Comment: That's caused by the interaction of the flat end cap and the buffer width.  I haven't been able to figure out a strategy to get rid of those.  Any idea what other systems produce in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row in `firstblock` has its own ID.

When you do the `lead(..)(PARTITION BY ID ..)`, it "breaks" the data for each ID, so there is a single row and therefore no previous (lead) row.

In this example, you can simply `order` the window function to find the previous row:

```
...
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ST_Area(the_geom) <= ST_Area(lead(the_geom) OVER(ORDER BY id))
        THEN ST_Difference(the_geom, lead(the_geom) OVER(ORDER BY id))
        ELSE ST_Difference(lead(the_geom) OVER(ORDER BY id), the_geom)
    END AS new_geom
FROM firstblocks;
```

eventually you could partition by `line_id`, and such `line_id` should be repeated in `firstblock` for each block of a given line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is working technically well, but for some reason single segments just dissappear from the geometry.

Comment: @DrSnuggles the entire `st_difference` logic is flawed. The 1st block has no previous (so the output of st_difference is null), and a block could return the geometry of the previous block. You can very likely end up with duplicates and holes (but this is a different question than making the lead() work)